# Retrieve desired data from xml file which has same name tags

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I publish some csv input file on a server and it gives me a xml file that looks like this:

```
<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
<ns0:deviceId>4567289456</ns0:deviceId>
.....
.....
</ns0:TransportationEvent>

<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
<ns0:deviceId>7965145741</ns0:deviceId>
.....
.....
</ns0:TransportationEvent>

<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
<ns0:deviceId>2168744654</ns0:deviceId>
.....
.....
</ns0:TransportationEvent>
```

The **TransportationEvent** tag would be added again and again with the updated deviceId in it.

I am retrieving data from this xml using XpathFactory class and NamespaceContext class which is shown as below:

```
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() { 
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) { 
            String uri; 
            if (prefix.equals("ns0")) 
                uri = "http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd"; 
            else 
                uri = null; 
            return uri; 
        } 
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) { 
            return null; 
        } 
        // Dummy implementation - not used! 
        public String getPrefix(String uri) { 
            return null; 
        } 
    };

XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

String strXpath = "//ns0:TransportationEvent/ns0:deviceId/text()";       
String deviceId = xpath.evaluate(strXpath, doc);
```

The above code gives the value of **deviceId** as *4567289456*. Basically it always take values from the first **TransportationEvent** tag.

I need to pick data from that "**TransportationEvent**" tag where the "**deviceId**" is equal to the deviceId of my choice. Something like this:

```
String strXpath = "//ns0:TransportationEvent[where ns0:deviceId = " + myDeviceId + "]/ns0:deviceId/text()";
```

I can perform this by using NodeList class and can iterate through all the "**TransportationEvent**" tags but then I would not be able to use the Xpath or NamespaceContext implementation. I am finding no connection between the NodeList class and the NamespaceContext class or the Xpath class.

I want to get the value of ***ctx*** which has the context of the desired **TransportationEvent** tag.

I know I am missing something. Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch the parent node of the deviceId you are intrested in like this:
`//ns0:deviceId[text()='7965145741']/parent::node()`

```
private static final String NS0_NS = "http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd";
private static final String NS0 = "ns0";
private static final List<String> prefixes = Arrays.asList(NS0);

public void fromDocument(Document doc) throws XPathExpressionException, TransformerConfigurationException,
        TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return prefixes.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {

            String res = namespaceURI.equals(NS0_NS)?NS0:null;
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            String res = prefix.equals(NS0)?NS0_NS:null;
            return res;
        }
    });

    XPathExpression devex = xpath.compile("//ns0:deviceId[text()='7965145741']/parent::node()");
    Node node = (Node) devex.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODE);

    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(new DOMSource(node),new StreamResult(System.out));
}
```

that's the output:

```
<ns0:TransportationEvent xmlns:ns0="http://www.server.com/schemas/TransportationEvent.xsd">
        <ns0:deviceId>7965145741</ns0:deviceId>
    </ns0:TransportationEvent>
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there any way to filter the required **TransportationEvent** with two fields. One field is _ns0:deviceId_ for whom you have shown already, plus if there is one more field e.g. _ns0:stopNumber_.
How can i add one more field(_ns0:stopNumber_) for filtering in this line:   
 **XPathExpression devex = xpath.compile("//ns0:deviceId[text()='7965145741']/parent::node()");**